# No playback on Ubuntu 20.04 java: LineUnavailableException thrown for every single mixer possible

Tags: java, audio, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to just play back some audio out of a WAV file in Ubuntu 20.04. I wrote code to catch LineUnavailableException and tried every single Mixer. Even though Mixer.isLineSupported() is true for all mixers selected, the exception is throw every time I call clip.open(ais)

I have no other audio playing, and shut down the browser and all processes except Eclipse.

When I export the jar and run it on Windows (I've got a dual boot laptop), it works first time,
so java.sound works on Windows, and with my hardware.

On Linux, the output are the System.out.println, several times (one exception per mixer tried):
"LUE caught: Line tried was unavailable"

And then lastly: "No Line Found".

My java version is:
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)

Is there something really broken about java.sound on Ubuntu 20.04?. My hardware:

$lspci
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

$aplay -l
PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3227 Analog [ALC3227 Analog]

```
class AudioPlay2 implements LineListener 
{
        File soundFile;
        JDialog playingDialog;
        Clip clip;

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            AudioPlay2 s = new AudioPlay2();
        }

        public AudioPlay2()
        {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            soundFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Playing " + soundFile.getName());       
            Line.Info lineInfo = new Line.Info(Clip.class);
            boolean foundLine = false;
            
            for (Mixer.Info mixerInfo : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) 
            {
                try
                {
                    Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo);
                    if (mixer.isLineSupported(lineInfo)) 
                    {
                        Line line = AudioSystem.getLine(lineInfo);
                        clip = (Clip) line;
                        clip.addLineListener(this);
                        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);
                        clip.open(ais);
                        foundLine = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (LineUnavailableException lue)
                {
                    System.out.println("LUE caught: Line tried was unavailable");
                    clip.removeLineListener(this);
                }
                catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Execption was " + e.getMessage());
                    clip.removeLineListener(this);
                }
            }       
                    
            
            if (foundLine)
            {
                clip.start();
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("No Line Found");
            }
        }

        public void update(LineEvent le) {
            LineEvent.Type type = le.getType();
            if (type == LineEvent.Type.OPEN) {
                System.out.println("OPEN");
            } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.CLOSE) {
                System.out.println("CLOSE");
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.START) {
                System.out.println("START");
                playingDialog.setVisible(true);
            } else if (type == LineEvent.Type.STOP) {
                System.out.println("STOP");
                playingDialog.setVisible(false);
                clip.close();
            }
        }
    }
```